# CWPack - What is a "data" in cw_pack_context_init?

Tags: c++, c, msgpack

I want to implement CWPack in my project, and I have hard time to understand it. If I understand it well, I have to make my variables to be cw_pack variables, and of course then make my functions and methods fit them. But I can't understand it here, where there is initiation of cw_pack object.

`int cw_pack_context_init (cw_pack_context* pack_context, void* data, unsigned long length, pack_overflow_handler hpo)`

As I know what void* is, i don't know what is the data I should give to this function. Anyone could help me or give some material to make me understand this by myself? Example from github in CWPack project doesn't help me.

Comment: `data` is the area of memory where you are going to pack your data. It's pretty fundamental to what CWPack is about so I'm wondering how good your understanding of CWPack is.

Comment: @john to be honest, I'm rookie in topic of CWPack, and in compression of data at all.

Comment: Well you can see from the example that they use a buffer of twenty bytes (the `data` array) and pack four values (not variables), a string, a bool, another string and an unsigned integer into it. They then unpack the same four values and check that they are correct.

Comment: And also CWPack is about *serialization* not compression. If you want compression then you should look elsewhere, zlib for instance. Though sometimes serialization would be the first step before compression takes place, so they can be related. Nevertheless CWPack isn't doing any compression.

Comment: @john now everything starts making sense. thanks!

Comment: @john make your comment as an answer so I will be able to mark it as solved problem